# Is it known issue that when user sets a fetchSize for JDBC drivers, the first retrieval is slower and subsequent calls are fast?

Tags: jdbc, database-performance, ojdbc, mssql-jdbc

```
try (Connection connection = DriverFactory.getConnectionForDriver(driverType); PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(PAGE_QUERY)) {
    ConnectionStopWatch watch = new ConnectionStopWatch().start();
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    rs.setFetchSize(userFetchSize);
    while (rs.next()) {
        rs.getString(2);
        rowCount++;
    }
    watch.stop();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the test case I had written to verify if fetchSize is honoured or not. 
In all cases, the rowCount was fixed for a particular driver. A new connection object is used each time.
Following is the output for above piece of test:

```
---------------------------------------------------
          DRIVER      ROWS      TIME IN MS     FETCH SIZE
---------------------------------------------------
           MSSQL     90276             519     10000
---------------------------------------------------
           MSSQL     90276             433     10000
---------------------------------------------------
           MSSQL     90276             437     10000
---------------------------------------------------
           MSSQL     90276             434     10000
---------------------------------------------------
           OJDBC       389              73     10000
---------------------------------------------------
           OJDBC       389               9     10000
---------------------------------------------------
           OJDBC       389               8     10000
---------------------------------------------------
           OJDBC       389               8     10000
---------------------------------------------------
```

Using Oracle 12 and SQL Server 2017.
Are subsequent fetch due some caching on database end? 
Or fetchSize is applicable after first fetch on that table? 
I had tried setting fetchSize on PreparedStatement as well, got the same result.
The query is a simple no brainer select star from a table.

Comment: It is unclear to what you're actually asking, and the table shown doesn't seem to provide any useful information that would say it is related to the fetch size. In any case the first request being slow and subsequent requests being fast has more likely to do with caching (filesystem cache, buffers and caches inside the database system, possibly including query plan caches), than anything else. The first request primes the cache, and subsequent requests benefit from this.

Comment: BTW, using fetch sizes of 10000 seems pretty excessive, and it is possible that a database system will ignore it and substitute it for a lower value. Fetch size is a trade-off between network latency and memory overhead.

Comment: Of course it's a 'known issue'. The first fetch includes the time to parse and execute the query and set up to deliver the result set. The later ones just read rows that are already in the pipeline. Some or all of that data may already have arrived at the client.

Comment: @user207421 The OP is re-executing queries, and the second, third, etc query is faster. So this is not about rows in the pipeline.